# AJAX Show Image after Upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

i working on uploading files using ajax for almost 3 hours and successfully managed to make it work, please check the code:

View

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Choose Image(s)", new { @class = "control-label col-sm-3" })
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input type="file" name="UploadFile" id="UploadFile" accept=".png, .jpg, .gif" multiple />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-3">
            <input type="button" value="Save" id="save" class="add btn btn-primary" />
            <div style="color:red">
                @ViewBag.error
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="margin-top: 17px;">

    @foreach (var item in Model.Content)
    {
        <div class="gallery">
            <a href="@item.ImagePath" title="@item.Description" data-gallery>
                <img src="@item.ThumbPath" alt="@item.Description" class="img-rounded" style="margin-bottom:7px;" />
            </a>
            <input type="button" class="delete btn btn-danger" value="Delete" data-picid="@item.PhotoId" />

        </div>
    }
    </div>
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Photo photo)
{
    var model = new Photo();
    foreach (string file in Request.Files)
    {
        var fileContent = Request.Files[file];
        if (fileContent.ContentLength == 0) continue;
        model.Description = photo.Description;
        var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileContent.FileName).ToLower();

        using (var img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fileContent.InputStream))
        {
            model.ThumbPath = String.Format(@"/GalleryImages/thumbs/{0}{1}", fileName, extension);
            model.ImagePath = String.Format(@"/GalleryImages/{0}{1}", fileName, extension);

            // Save thumbnail size image, 100 x 100
            SaveToFolder(img, fileName, extension, new Size(200, 200), model.ThumbPath);

            // Save large size image, 800 x 800
            SaveToFolder(img, fileName, extension, new Size(600, 600), model.ImagePath);
        }

        // Save record to database
        model.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
        db.Photos.Add(model);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

     return Json("File Uploaded Successfully");
}
```

JQuery/AJAX

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#UploadFile').on('change', function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var files = e.target.files;
        if (files.length > 0) {
            if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
                var data = new FormData();
                for (var x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {
                    data.append("file" + x, files[x]);
                }
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/Home/Create',
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: data,
                    success: function (result) {
                        console.log(result);
                        //add code to refresh the gallery with the new uploaded image
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
                        var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3 + " p4;
                        if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
                            err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).Message;
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                alert("Error! This browser does not support file upload, please change your browser");
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

SavetoFolder

```
private void SaveToFolder(Image img, string fileName, string extension, Size newSize, string pathToSave)
{
    // Get new image resolution
    Size imgSize = NewImageSize(img.Size, newSize);
    using (System.Drawing.Image newImg = new Bitmap(img, imgSize.Width, imgSize.Height))
    {
        newImg.Save(Server.MapPath(pathToSave), img.RawFormat);
    }
}
```

NewImageSize

```
public Size NewImageSize(Size imageSize, Size newSize)
{
    Size finalSize;
    double tempval;
    if (imageSize.Height > newSize.Height || imageSize.Width > newSize.Width)
    {
        if (imageSize.Height > imageSize.Width)
            tempval = newSize.Height / (imageSize.Height * 1.0);
        else
            tempval = newSize.Width / (imageSize.Width * 1.0);

        finalSize = new Size((int)(tempval * imageSize.Width), (int)(tempval * imageSize.Height));
    }
    else
        finalSize = imageSize; // image is already small size

    return finalSize;
}
```

but the problem is i have to refresh the browser to see the added image, what should i put in ajax on sucess upload to add the image dynamically without refreshing browser?

Comment: Along with Json `success` message return image's **Thumb path/Image path** and render it to `DOM` in `success` or return the `model` itself.. If possible share your `SaveToFolder` code

Comment: added savetofolder code

Comment: Also `NewImageSize` method.. :)

Comment: hehe i see what your up to.

Comment: Come to chat.. Need some more details...

Comment: guru i need your help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33590177/multiple-image-file-upload-but-same-caption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are having option to upload **multiple images** I would suggest to go with below approach:

your controller now would look like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Photo photo)
{
    List<Photo> model = new List<Photo>();
    //create list of photo model
    foreach (string file in Request.Files)
    {
        var fileContent = Request.Files[file];
        if (fileContent.ContentLength == 0) continue;
        var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileContent.FileName).ToLower();
        string thumpath,imagepath = "";
        using (var img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fileContent.InputStream))
        {
              model.Add(new Photo(){
                  Description=photo.Description,
                  ThumbPath = String.Format(@"/GalleryImages/thumbs/{0}{1}", fileName, extension),
                  ImagePath = String.Format(@"/GalleryImages/{0}{1}", fileName, extension),
                  CreatedOn=DateTime.Now
              });
              //fill each detail of model here
              thumpath = String.Format(@"/GalleryImages/thumbs/{0}{1}", fileName, extension);
              //separate variables to send it to SaveToFolder Method
              imagepath = String.Format(@"/GalleryImages/{0}{1}", fileName, extension);
              SaveToFolder(img, fileName, extension, new Size(200, 200), thumpath);

              SaveToFolder(img, fileName, extension, new Size(600, 600), imagepath);
         }
    }
    foreach(var md in model)
    {
        //loop again for each content in model
        db.Photos.Add(md);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return Json(new {model=model },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    //return the model here
}
```

in `ajax success` you can create the image with the model returned values as below:

```
success: function (result) {
     var model = result.model;
     $(model).each(function (key,value) {
           $('<img />').attr({
                 src: value.ThumbPath
           }).appendTo("body");
           //note you can append it to anywhere, like inside container or something
     })
}
```

Comment: hello guru can we speak in chat i need help with something

Comment: cant create a room yet

Answer (score 0):

I would set the src attribute of the img tag usign jQuery in your success function:

```
  success: function (result) {
       $("img").attr('src' , '/path/to/your/img');
  },
```

If you don't know the public path to your image on client side you can use the response object:

```
 return Json("{ path : "+model.ImagePath+"."+fileName+"."+extension+"}");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a few possibilities, which to use depends on pictures size etc. 
Personaly I (if images are not too big) would on server side convert image ot base64 and return it with ajax and display the data returned from server, of course it would need conversion as well.

Check out this article, i think i'll help you :)

[Base64 encoded image](http://danielmclaren.com/node/90)

Comment: right, ill convert the image to base64 in my controller then how would that work in ajax?

Comment: You would just return from controller base64 encoded value and insert into you html like `div.html('<img src="'+returned_data+'">')`