# Multiple Image File Upload with Captions

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I managed to get the captions by `foreach` loop but now I'm facing a new problem.

I get duplicates in my database because of the nested loop, please check the code below.

JavaScript

```js
window.onload = function () {
    if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
        var filesInput = document.getElementById("galleryFilesAdd");
        filesInput.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
            var files = event.target.files; //FileList object
            var output = document.getElementById("result");
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                var file = files[i];
                if (!file.type.match('image'))
                    continue;
                var picReader = new FileReader();
                picReader.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
                    var picFile = event.target;
                    var div = document.createElement("div");
                    div.innerHTML = "<img class='thumbnail img-responsive' alt='" + picFile.name + "' + height='220' width='300'; src='" + picFile.result + "'" +
                            "title='" + picFile.name + "'/><button type='button' class='delete btn btn-default' class='remove_pic'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span></button><input type='text' id ='imagecaption[]' name='imagecaption[]' class='form-control' placeholder='Add Image Caption'>"
                    output.insertBefore(div, null);
                    div.children[1].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
                    });
                });
                //Read the image
                picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        console.log("Your browser does not support File API");
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult> AddHotel(HotelViewModels.AddHotel viewModel, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> galleryFilesAdd)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            foreach (var files in galleryFilesAdd)
            {
                var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
                var extension = Path.GetExtension(files.FileName).ToLower();
                string thumbpath, imagepath = "";
                using (var img = Image.FromStream(files.InputStream))
                {
                  foreach (var caption in viewModel.imagecaption)
                  {
                    var galleryImg = new hotel_gallery_image
                    {
                        hotel_id = hotel.id,
                        thumbPath = String.Format("/Resources/Images/Hotel/GalleryThumb/{0}{1}", fileName, extension),
                        imagePath = String.Format("/Resources/Images/Hotel/Gallery/{0}{1}", fileName, extension),
                        entry_datetime = DateTime.Now,
                        guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"),
                        enabled = true,
                        image_caption = caption
                    };
                    db.hotel_gallery_image.Add(galleryImg);
                }
            }
          }

            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Hotel");
        }
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
    {
        string errorMessages = string.Join("; ", ex.EntityValidationErrors.SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors).Select(x => x.PropertyName + ": " + x.ErrorMessage));
        throw new DbEntityValidationException(errorMessages);
    }
    viewModel.Country = await db.countries.ToListAsync();
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

and viewModel

```
public string[] imagecaption { get; set; }
```

Inserted data into database

[image]

Comment: any help guys? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your

```
image_caption = viewModel.imagecaption
```

because you iterate through `var files in galleryFilesAdd`you use the reference to the same `image_caption` from `viewModel` on each iteration, so you need to filter your `image_caption` depending on another data (fileName or another data which you `viewmodel` contains).

**UPDATE**
Ideally if you have same properties in your ViewModel and files(filename for example), then you could do something like `thatimage_caption = viewModel.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Filename == filename).imagecaption`

In order to be more specific would be helpful if you provide code for your `Viemodel` and `galleryFilesAdd` classes.

**UPDATE 2**

In your case 2nd foreach you iterate through **whole** collection of `imagecaption` array, on each iteration through `galleryFilesAdd` collection, which cause double data in you database.
If you can take your captions sequentially  for the 1st file take the 1st element from imagecaption array and so on then you can use code like this:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            int index = 0;
            foreach (var files in galleryFilesAdd)
            {
                var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
                var extension = Path.GetExtension(files.FileName).ToLower();
                string thumbpath, imagepath = "";
                using (var img = Image.FromStream(files.InputStream))
                {
                 if(index < viewModel.imagecaption.Length){
                    var galleryImg = new hotel_gallery_image
                    {
                        hotel_id = hotel.id,
                        thumbPath = String.Format("/Resources/Images/Hotel/GalleryThumb/{0}{1}", fileName, extension),
                        imagePath = String.Format("/Resources/Images/Hotel/Gallery/{0}{1}", fileName, extension),
                        entry_datetime = DateTime.Now,
                        guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"),
                        enabled = true,
                        image_caption = viewModel.imagecaption[index]
                    };
                    db.hotel_gallery_image.Add(galleryImg);
                    index++;
                   }
            }
          }
```

Comment: hi there how can i filter image caption depending on my file uploaded?

Comment: i have tried making my imagecaption private string[] imagecaption then use foreach loop to update the image caption